# Task Scheduler won't start various programs on startup

Tags: windows-8, boot, task-scheduler

For example it starts SpeedFan without any problem, and with same settings, or even in the same Task, if I add for example other .exe software like FTP server software Gene6 FTP Server it simply doesn't start for any reason and nothing happens and it has to be started manually by mouse-clicking on .exe each time computer is booted up.

On Last Run Result column it says 0x800702E4. And it gives various 0x results for various programs that don't run.

Comment: 0x800702E4 = ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED configure the task to run with highest privileges.

Comment: I can't select your comment as correct answer. You should use Answer question button. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error 0x800702E4 means ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED.

```
C:\Users\André>err 0x800702E4
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_WIN32 (0x7), Code 0x2e4
# for hex 0x2e4 / decimal 740
  ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED                                       winerror.h
# The requested operation requires elevation.
# 1 matches found for "0x800702E4"
```

You must configure your task to be run with highest privileges.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to running at highest privileges, I had to switch the "Configure For" option to be Windows Server 2016.

Like this:
[image]